# How do you eliminate catastrophic backtracing from a regular expression

Tags: regex

I have developed the following regular expression to parse some racing data:

```
^(\w+\s?\w+)-?(\w+\s?\w+)?-?(\w+\s?\w+)?\s(\(.*?\))-?(\w+\s?\w+)-?(\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+)?-?(\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+)?\s(\(.*?\))-?(\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+)-?(\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+)?-?(\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+)?\s(\(.*?\))-?(\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+)-?\s(\(.*?\))-?
```

The regex forks fine for most of my data (see examples) [This works great](https://regex101.com/r/9qsN8d/1/)

But for certain text data I'm getting a Catastrophic Backtracing error and I can't figure out the reason why.   (see examples)[This fails](https://regex101.com/r/XjY2Bo/1/)

Is there something I can change in my regular expression so I don't get the error. Also what is it about the strings that fail that cause the failure?

Comment: The link to the failing text seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Can you explain in brief prose terms what the regex is supposed to match?

Comment: The regex is simply suppose to parse the string to facilitate additional downstream processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious red flags: Your regex contains `.*?`, which is always a bad idea (too unconstrained). It also contains `\w+\s?\w+-?\w+` etc., which (since the delimiters are all optional) can be matched as `\w+\w+\w+` etc., which can lead to catastrophic backtracking because all the `\w+` matches can overlap.

That is, a string like `foobar` can be matched by `\w+\w+\w+` as `foob` `a` `r` or `f` `o` `obar` or `fo` `ob` `ar` or anything in between. All of these are morally equivalent (the same substring is covered by the regex match), but if a later part of the regex causes a match failure, the regex engine will cycle through all possible ways to split up `foobar` between `\w+\w+\w+` before giving up and returning failure.

The solution is to make sure that the subparts of your regex can never overlap.

For example, to match one or two space-separated words, you should use `\w+(?:\s\w+)?`, not `\w+\s?\w+`.